# Bootstrap Affix-bottom not scrolling back up

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, affix

I have read some other answers but have still not been able to get the settings right.

The columsheader does not start scrolling up again.

Here is my php:

```
<div id="columnsHeader" class="affix" data-offset-top="800" data-offset-bottom="400" data-spy="affix">
```

Here is my **css**:

```
.itemList {
position: relative;
}

.extrafieldscolumnsHeader {
position: absolute;
top: -25px;
width: 818px;
color:white;
min-height: 28px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left:8px;
}

#columnsHeader.affix {
border-top: 40px solid #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
top: 43px;
width: 818px;
}

#columnsHeader.affix-bottom {
position: absolute; /* Start scrolling again. */
top: auto; /* Override the top position above. */
bottom: 55px; /* It should stop near the bottom of its parent. */
}
```

Here is the **temp url**:

```
http://108.163.203.210/~goodwin/xjoomla/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=12&Itemid=143
```

Comment: what do you mean? I checked the link I don't know what's wrong. Maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez  Thanks for checking it out.  Scroll all the way down and make sure your browser height is short enough to trigger the affix-bottom.  When you scroll back up the columnsheader does not scroll up with you.

Comment: It is still getting stuck on affix-bottom,

Answer (score 0):

i think this may works for you and you just need to set `margin-bottom` of `<BODY>`respect to your footer...

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <button class="filter">filter &#9654;</button>
    <button class="wgit">wGit &#9654;</button>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
body > footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
body > footer > button{
    font-size: 16px;
    float: right;
    margin:5px 15px 5px 10px;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
body > footer > button:hover{
    color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #c3c3c3 inset;
}
.filter-child {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    right:15px;
    bottom:50px;
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px dashed #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.filter-child li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.filter-child li:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #3a3a3a inset;
}
.filter-child  a{
    color: #000000;
}
```

and you can follow this links also...
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Tirthrajsinth, thanks but I don't need a sticky footer.